# How many Qubits does the qiskit implementation of Shor's Algorithm need to factor N=15?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I know there is a documentation for [qiskit.aqua.algorithms.Shor](https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.single_sample.Shor.html) that explains that they used [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205095) reference for implementing the actual circuit. It says that the number of qubit needed is 2n+3. So to factor N=15, 11 qubits would be needed. I decided to test this using Qiskit with a backend that has up to 15 qubits. But then I get an error saying that I needed 18 qubits to factor N = 15. Is the implementation different from the actual paper referenced? or am I missing something ?

This is the code I used to factor N=15

```
shor = Shor(15,2)
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, skip_qobj_validation=False)
res = shor.run(quantum_instance)
print("The list of factors of {} as computed by Shor is {}.".format(PRIME, res['factors'][0]))
```

And this is the error i got

```
TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (18) in circuit1 is greater than maximum (15) in the coupling_TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (18) in circuit1 is greater than maximum (15) in the coupling_map'
```

Comment: Have you tried running on a different backend like a simulator? If on simulator it uses 11, my guess would be that running on a real hardware instance may have another layer of computation to adapt to the architecture.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. Yes, I have tried using the qasm_simulator backend it has up to 32 qubits and it does factor N=15, but I don't know if there is a way of checking how many qubits were used in the process. I am now reading about the actual source code of the implementation, and the paper it's based on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually when looking at the source code, the construct_circuit method:

> ## quantum register where the sequential QFT is performed
>
> ```
>     self._up_qreg = QuantumRegister(2 * self._n, name='up')
>     # quantum register where the multiplications are made
>     self._down_qreg = QuantumRegister(self._n, name='down')
>     # auxiliary quantum register used in addition and multiplication
>     self._aux_qreg = QuantumRegister(self._n + 2, name='aux')
> ```

They use indeed $4n + 2$ qubits, so it seems they changed what was proposed in the paper. Some parts were simplified. Check the docstring in the [original github repo](https://github.com/ttlion/ShorAlgQiskit/blob/master/Shor_Normal_QFT.py).

Comment: Thanks a lot !, I figured it was something like that but couldn't find some explanation to it. I guess ill be looking at studying the source code at the original git repo a bit more